# What tools can be used to debug managed code from the command line?

Tags: c#, .net

What tools can be used to debug managed code from the command line (in a fashion similar to GDB)?

After having done a little research, I see that mdbg.exe may have fulfilled a similar purpose in the past (however it appears to have been removed from the Windows 8 SDK). I've started looking into cdb.exe, but as of yet cannot get it to list source lines or set breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cdb.exe is an unmanaged debugger, the console version of Windbg.exe.  It does support the SOS extension that permits peeking at internal CLR structures but rarely what you are looking for when simply debugging managed code.

MDbg was removed from the SDK, it wasn't compatible with the updated debugger interfaces in .NET 4.  It took them a while to get it updated.  But that was ultimately done, you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282).

Comment: Couldn't be more pleased. Thanks!